# In $\mathbb{Z}_2$, is $x^5+x+1$ and $1+x^6$ in the ideal generated by $1+x^2$ and $1+x^3$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> In $\mathbb{Z}_2$, is $x^5+x+1$ and $1+x^6$ in the ideal generated by $1+x^2$ and $1+x^3$?

Since $1$ is a root of $1+x^2$ and $1+x^3$, then if $p(x)\in \langle 1+x^2, 1+x^3\rangle$, then $p(1)=0$. Therefore $x^5+x+1$ is not in the ideal.

But how to determine if $1+x^6$ is in the ideal?

I can factorize $1+x^2=(x+1)^2$ and $x^3+1=(x+1)(x^2+x+1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a general approach, you probably want to:

1. Take the polynomial GCD of $1+x^2$ and $1+x^3$ to show that $\langle 1+x^2, 1+x^3 \rangle = \langle 1+x \rangle$ (over $\mathbb Z_2$, of course).
2. Use polynomial long division to divide $1+x^6$ by $1+x$ and see if you get a remainder. (Of course, for $1+x$ in particular, this is equivalent to setting $x=1$ and seeing if you get $0$.)

In practice, your degrees are small and $\mathbb Z_2$ is so nice to work with that after some practice, you can just spot the factorizations that solve the problem for you.

Comment: Why $\langle 1+x^2,1+x^3\rangle =\langle 1+x \rangle$? For example, $1+x$ is not in $\langle 1+x^2,1+x^3\rangle$.

Comment: Yes it is: $1+x = x\cdot(1+x^2) + 1\cdot(1+x^3)$.

Comment: Sorry. So you mean $\langle p(x),q(x) \rangle = \langle gcd(p,q) \rangle$? Is it because that $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ is a PID?

Comment: Yes, and yes. In fact, one definition of GCD is that $\gcd(a,b)$ is the thing such that $\langle a,b\rangle = \langle \gcd(a,b)\rangle$. (Moreover, $\mathbb Z_2[x]$ is a Euclidean domain, not just a PID, which is why we can compute the GCD of things easily.)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use the fact
\begin{align}
1+x^6=1+2x^3+x^6=(1+x^3)^2.
\end{align}